# Basic difference betwen setstate and other state management like provider in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, state, provider

Basic difference betwen setstate and other state management like provider in flutter ,I am beginner to flutter, where to use provider instead of set state ,

if we set state what's is disadvantages of set state when more usage of the app

Comment: I hope it helpful 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flutter-difference-between-setstate-and-provider-in-state-management/

Comment: Basically the main difference is that with setState you have the state in the view and with state management you can separate the logic. This makes it more scalable and maintainable. SetState can be used when the state only exists within a widget and no other part of your app needs to access this state.

Answer (score 1):

A high-level explanation here is that calling `setState()` rebuilds the entire screen. Whereas when you're using state management like provider or bloc, you can utilize Streams. This should allow you to rebuild specific portions of the Screen using Widgets like [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) - which can be rebuilt when changes in Stream has been made.